# nodejs (NestJs) AWS Elastic Beanstalk Issue (with aws pipeline)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pipeline, nestjs

I have red docs many times and I still have problem with deploy my project on Elastic Beanstalk.

I have created ready build solution which works without problems on my local computer.

The structure looks like this:

[image]

also I have created pipeline as AWS service:

[image]

According to the documentation, I created buildspec.yaml file:
(it just creates dist folder, puts files into it, install node_modules takes together and makes zip file)

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
    commands:
      - yum install -y zip
      - echo "Instal dependencies"
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build
      - cd dist
      - zip -r application.zip ./* ../package.json ../package-lock.json ../.env ../node_modules ../Procfile
      - cd ..
      - mv ./dist/application.zip ./
artifacts:
  files:
    - application.zip
```

It creates artifact as zip and puts into E3 bucket when I download it the structure is the same as in my local computer:

[image]

According to docs I have included Procfile which is used during deploy action:

```
web: node app.js
```

The problem occurs during deployment. I receive error from Elastic Beanstalk:

```
2020/08/04 16:58:49.766428 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2020/08/04 16:58:49.917998 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2020/08/04 16:58:49.918039 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544212 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544764 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunPreBuildHooks
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544792 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544797 [INFO] Executing instruction: Install customer specified node.js version
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544802 [INFO] installing specified nodejs version...
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544809 [INFO] there is no package.json file, skip installing specified version of nodejs
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544814 [INFO] Executing instruction: Use NPM to install dependencies
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544822 [INFO] there is no package.json file, skip installing dependencies
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544827 [INFO] Executing instruction: check Procfile
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544831 [INFO] checking Procfile
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544837 [INFO] no Procfile found, generating Procfile
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544841 [INFO] checking package.json file
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544847 [INFO] checking app.js file from source
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544853 [INFO] checking server.js file from source
2020/08/04 16:58:50.544867 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [check Procfile]. Stop running the command. Error: node.js may have issues starting. Please provide a package.json file or add server.js/app.js file in source bundle
```

In my opinion deploy pipeline part does not recive artifacts because it does not see package.json, Procfile and also app.js main file.

In addtion I would like to show you that i have established artifacts connection between deploy and build section:
[image]

When I upload file manually - it works..
What am I doing wrong? Thnaks in advice!

Comment: "When I upload file manually" -  you mean that when you upload the zip artifact produced by CB it all works as expected? Also what the `Details` in deploy stage say?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and decided to change my approach to not use the zip method. Here's my build config file.

```
version: 0.2

#env:
  #variables:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #parameter-store:
     # key: "value"
     # key: "value"
  #secrets-manager:
     # key: secret-id:json-key:version-stage:version-id
     # key: secret-id:json-key:version-stage:version-id
  #exported-variables:
     # - variable
     # - variable
  #git-credential-helper: yes
#batch:
  #fast-fail: true
  #build-list:
  #build-matrix:
  #build-graph:
phases:
  install:
    #If you use the Ubuntu standard image 2.0 or later, you must specify runtime-versions.
    #If you specify runtime-versions and use an image other than Ubuntu standard image 2.0, the build fails.
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14
      # name: version
    commands:
      - echo "Instal dependencies"
      - npm install
  #pre_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build
  #post_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
#reports:
  #report-name-or-arn:
    #files:
      # - location
      # - location
    #base-directory: location
    #discard-paths: yes
    #file-format: JunitXml | CucumberJson
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
    # - location
  #name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  #discard-paths: yes
  #base-directory: location
#cache:
  #paths:
    # - paths
```

And in my Procfile, I added this line:

```
web: npm run start:prod
```

And it worked like a charm.